# Applying style using JS when Content Security Policy is in effect

Tags: css, content-security-policy

I'm trying to set an element's background color using Javascript, and I have a Content Security Policy with `style-src 'self'`.

I'm able to do things like `$(el).css("display", "none")` from Javascript, but `$(el).css("background-color", "#FFF")` fails due to the CSP. The same happens when I try doing `el.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF"`.

The `#FFF` is actually coming from the database, so I don't have a way of putting that into a static CSS file. Is there any way that I can set the background color dynamically without allowing all inline style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that `el` was inside a block managed by Tooltipster. Tooltipster clones the content of the tooltip before displaying it, so even though the style was actually set successfully on the original `el`, when the clone was inserted into the DOM, the browser saw that the element had a style tag, and blocked it.